# How to use RCTRootView in a view controller?

Tags: ios, react-native, native-module

I am working on react native iOS app(demo). And new to the react native. I want to know about the `RCTRootView` i.e how it is work. And I have a doubt i.e. in the `app delegate` the root view is created default. If I added another root view in my `view controller` what happens? And it set which one will be the root view.Can anyone help me on this? And what happens if I create it with the new module name?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new Xcode project, it'll specify a storyboard (*Main.storyboard*) to be your "Main Interface". You can see this in the "General" settings tab of your target. In that storyboard you will find the Storyboard Entry Point, an arrow on the left side of the View Controller. This indicates that the View Controller (which by default is of class `ViewController`) will be your root view controller. If you remove the "Main Interface" setting (so that it's empty), you will not have a root view controller automatically; you will have to set it up manually.

Take a look at the examples that are available for ReactNative. You will see that the general approach is that in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` a `UIWindow` is instantiated, followed by a plain `UIViewController`. At some point before or after that, the `RCTRootView` is instantiated (either using an `RCTBridge` or the `BundleURL: moduleName:...` initializer). This is a subclass of `UIView` so it doesn't have a `UIViewController` yet. Therefore it is then set as the view of the earlier mentioned plain `UIViewController`, which is then set as the `rootViewController` of the `UIWindow`, which is made "key and visible", after which we're ready.

I have been working with ReactNative for only two days now, but seeing the above pattern repeatedly, I see myself today building something like an `RCTRootViewController` to encapsulate it, passing the `RCTRootView` in the `loadView` method of the `UIViewController`. The view controller can have initialisers that match the ones of the `RCTRootView`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got the solutions for my question.

Comment: @Ramakrishna can you please share your solution.